# Is there a neater Typescript idiom for throwing an error in case a value is undefined at runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dotenv

I'm using dotenv to load some values are runtime. I want to throw an error in the case the value is undefined. Is there a neater way of doing this in Typescript than the following?

```
    dotenv.config()
    if (process.env.USERNAME == undefined) {
        throw new Error("USERNAME is undefined")
    }
    let username:string = process.env.USERNAME
```

Comment: TypeScript doesn't affect runtime. You're really looking for JavaScript idioms here.

Comment: I would probably just do `if (!process.env.USERNAME) throw new Error("USERNAME is undefined")`.  No other idiom I know of.

Comment: @jfriend00 I suppose there is [`assert`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_value_message). It's sort of an idiom, at least in other languages. It's also usually a bad idiom and there ways to handle the checks.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yeah, assert would work.  I don't know why, but I think of assert as meant for development testing, not for production use, but it could work here.  Maybe that's back from my C++ days where asserts were preprocessed out in the final code.

Comment: Yes to a point Patrick Roberts. The context of this code is that I'd be happy for the Javascript to bomb out if the value is undefined. It is the Typescript type checker that needs me to be explicit about that - a later API call wants a defined string.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js has the [`assert`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) module for purposes like this, though [`@types/assert`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/assert/index.d.ts) fails to declare the functions in this module as [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates), so the assertions will also need to be done separately using TypeScript at compile-time.

```
import assert from 'assert';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

assert.notStrictEqual(process.env.USERNAME, undefined, 'USERNAME is undefined');

let username: string = process.env.USERNAME;
```

Comment: I suspect the OP isn't actually looking only for `undefined`.  They probably also don't want an empty string.  So, maybe `assert.ok(process.env.USERNAME, 'USERNAME is undefined')`